# Is there a specification of x86 I/O port assignment?

Tags: assembly, io, x86, port, specifications

I found some information on the web as follows, but incomplete.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_base_address

http://wiki.osdev.org/I/O_Ports

Where to download the specification?

Comment: Have you found any official documents regarding IO port assignment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A good source for *current* (and not from 1994) I/O port map is chipset documentation, e.g. [Intel® 7 Series Chipset Family PCH Datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/7-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf) (see section 9.3, I/O Map). For example, here are some ports which are commonly used in modern PCs and are not mentioned in the old lists:

- 2E-2F,4E-4F: Low Pin Count (LPC) interface, usually connected to Super I/O or EC (Embedded Controller)
- 0CF8, 0CFC: PCI configuration space access
- B2: ACPI and SMI port (writing to it usually generates an SMI interrupt)

Note that some I/O ranges are dynamic and can be moved by reprogramming various bits in the corresponding PCI devices configuration.

Comment: Are those IO ports 8-bit or 16-bit? Because I've seen them being used with 8-bit CPU registers (out dx,al) as well as 16-bit ones (out dx,ax). What does happen when I write a 16-bit value from a register to some port address? Is it being written to two consecutive IO addresses? Or just one? How can I know the size of the target IO port?

Comment: @SasQ can be both: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20335/60

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check [Ralf Brown's interrupt list "RBIL"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html).

[Part D](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/interrupt-list/inter61d.zip) contains the information on I/O ports.

Answer (score 3):

For classic (i.e. pre-1995) information on ports, the Bochs project has a very useful list of [XT, AT and PS/2 port addresses](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/techspec/PORTS.LST). The list is fairly comprehensive, although the preamble warns the reader to "not consider this information as complete and accurate".